# Modifying source code in Jenkins with npm-check-updates

Tags: node.js, shell, jenkins, npm, package.json

I am trying to get Jenkins to pull my git repo, run `npm-check-updates`, run tests and builds, and then push back to the repo.

For the most part every individual piece seems to be working, however the npm-check-updates task isn't persiting the updates of my `package.json`

Here is the relevent part of the shell script

```
ncu -x "typescript" -l silly
ncu -x "typescript" -u -a -l silly
cat package.json
```

Here are the output logs for this section. As you can see, ncu indicates the updates that have taken place, but the `package.json` is not reflecting those updates

```
+ ncu -x typescript -l silly
Initializing...
Running in local mode...
Finding package file data...
Waiting for package data on stdin...
Using /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my-project/package.json
Getting installed packages...
Fetching latest versions...

 @types/jasmine         ~2.5.53  →   ~2.8.3 
 @types/node            ~6.0.60  →  ~7.0.52 
 jasmine-core            ~2.6.2  →   ~2.8.0 
 jasmine-spec-reporter   ~4.1.0  →   ~4.2.1 
 karma                   ~1.7.0  →   ~2.0.0 
 karma-chrome-launcher   ~2.1.1  →   ~2.2.0 
 protractor              ~5.1.2  →   ~5.2.2 
 ts-node                 ~3.2.0  →   ~4.1.0 
 tslint                  ~5.7.0  →   ~5.8.0 

The following dependencies are satisfied by their declared version range,
but the installed versions are behind. You can install the latest versions 
without modifying your package file by using npm update. If you want to 
update the dependencies in your package file anyway, run ncu -a.

 @angular/animations                 ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 @angular/common                     ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 @angular/compiler                   ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 @angular/core                       ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 @angular/forms                      ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 @angular/http                       ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 @angular/platform-browser           ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic   ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 @angular/router                     ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 core-js                             ^2.4.1  →   ^2.5.3 
 rxjs                                ^5.5.2  →   ^5.5.6 
 zone.js                            ^0.8.14  →  ^0.8.19 
 @angular/compiler-cli               ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 @angular/language-service           ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 @types/jasminewd2                   ~2.0.2  →   ~2.0.3 
 codelyzer                           ^4.0.1  →   ^4.0.2 
 karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter    ^1.2.1  →   ^1.3.3 
 karma-jasmine                       ~1.1.0  →   ~1.1.1 

+ ncu -x typescript -u -a -l silly
Initializing...
Running in local mode...
Finding package file data...
Waiting for package data on stdin...
Using /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my-project/package.json
Getting installed packages...
Fetching latest versions...

 @types/jasmine         ~2.5.53  →   ~2.8.3 
 @types/node            ~6.0.60  →  ~7.0.52 
 jasmine-core            ~2.6.2  →   ~2.8.0 
 jasmine-spec-reporter   ~4.1.0  →   ~4.2.1 
 karma                   ~1.7.0  →   ~2.0.0 
 karma-chrome-launcher   ~2.1.1  →   ~2.2.0 
 protractor              ~5.1.2  →   ~5.2.2 
 ts-node                 ~3.2.0  →   ~4.1.0 
 tslint                  ~5.7.0  →   ~5.8.0 
 @angular/animations                 ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 @angular/common                     ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 @angular/compiler                   ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 @angular/core                       ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 @angular/forms                      ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 @angular/http                       ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 @angular/platform-browser           ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic   ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 @angular/router                     ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 core-js                             ^2.4.1  →   ^2.5.3 
 rxjs                                ^5.5.2  →   ^5.5.6 
 zone.js                            ^0.8.14  →  ^0.8.19 
 @angular/compiler-cli               ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 @angular/language-service           ^5.0.0  →   ^5.1.3 
 @types/jasminewd2                   ~2.0.2  →   ~2.0.3 
 codelyzer                           ^4.0.1  →   ^4.0.2 
 karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter    ^1.2.1  →   ^1.3.3 
 karma-jasmine                       ~1.1.0  →   ~1.1.1 

+ cat package.json
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "validate": "npm-run-all --parallel e2e lint",
    "prepush": "npm run validate"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that one of the known issues for another problem (hanging) is a fix for this Jenkins issue - https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates#known-issues

Specifying the package file with `--packageFile package.json` worked.